# Fun with numbers - JLU usage graphs

Tags: discussion, site-health

I've put together some charts that track JLU's beta health meters at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526?phase=beta) on an hourly basis.

- User related stats: http://webnumbr.com/.join(jlu-beta-total-users.all,jlu-beta-avid-users.all,jlu-beta-visits-per-day.all).default
- Question related stats: http://webnumbr.com/.join(jlu-beta-questions-per-day.all,jlu-beta-answers-per-question.all).default

(Thanks to [WebNumbr](http://webnumbr.com/).)

Notes on usage:

- **Don't jump to conclusions!** These charts are only a few days old, as of this writing. You should wait at least more than two weeks to see if there is a general trend.
- **Interpret with caution!** I implore you to read this article ["Does this site have a chance of succeeding?"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/) before drawing any conclusion from the numbers.

So, to all the numberphiles out there, enjoy!

Comment: Cool data-crunching job! As you say, I'm not sure it can be interpreted to much yet, but always interesting to see the trend...

Comment: Interesting?  I do not know.  Fun?  Yes.

Comment: おもしろいですよね =D ...

Comment: good to see a steady rise in visits and users... but that's a huge dropoff in avg questions or recent